puppeteer launch args '--disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies,CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure' not working
below is my launch config
 {
        "headless": false,
        "ignoreDefaultArgs": true,
        "args": [
          "--flag-switches-begin",
          "--start-maximized",
          "--disable-web-security",
          "--disable-site-isolation-trials",
          "--disable-features=IsolateOrigins",
          "--disable-features=site-per-process",
          "--disable-features=BlockInsecurePrivateNetworkRequests",
          "--force-device-scale-factor=1",
          "--disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies,CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure",
          "--flag-switches-end"
        ],
        "defaultViewport": null,
        "executablePath": "./puppeteer/win64-843427/chrome-win/chrome.exe"
      }
 }

after chrome launched, the disabled features not working.

the chrome://version as below
Google Chrome   90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Revision    e3cd97fc771b893b7fd1879196d1215b622c2bed-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#1429}
OS  Windows 10 OS Version 2009 (Build 19044.1288)
JavaScript  V8 9.0.257.29
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36
Command Line    "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-y4emnt" --flag-switches-begin --start-maximized --disable-web-security --disable-features=IsolateOrigins --disable-features=site-per-process --force-device-scale-factor=1 --disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies,CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure --flag-switches-end --remote-debugging-port=0 --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
Executable Path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Profile Path    C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-y4emnt\Default
Variations  5e3a236d-4113a79e

then, i modify the command line without the --user-data-dir setting, launch again from console, the falgs disabled as expected.
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --start-maximized --disable-web-security --disable-features=IsolateOrigins --disable-features=site-per-process --force-device-scale-factor=1 --disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies,CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure --flag-switches-end --remote-debugging-port=0 --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end

seem the auto generated userDataDir will overwrite my args setting.

how to let my args setting with the top priority and let the flags disabled? thanks
